# Проблема с NuPlayer 5.x

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Пишу игру, использую для воспроизведения звука

```
mPWind = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wind1);
mPWind.setLooping(true);
mPWind.start();
```

Как уже известно, используя looping в 5.x все равно что горохом о стену: из-за NuPlayer луп не работает. Выход есть - в настройках разработчика сменить на Awesome. Но кодом это сделать нельзя.

Как мне все же заставить приложение воспроизводить музыку циклично, с повтором? Может есть еще плееры? Скажу сразу - саунд пул не подойдет- треки длинные.